# Istio fault injection

Tags: istio

Istio supports [fault injecting](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/fault-injection/).

The example is using `destination`.  Is there any way for me to use `source` in order to inject fault to downstream services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `sourceLabels` with internal `mesh` gateway.
Example:

```yaml
gateways:
  - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - sourceLabels:
        app: source-app-v1
```

read [HTTPMatchRequest](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest) for more.

---

Unfortunately, there is no straightforward way to achieve what you looking for.

`route.destination.host` is a required field for [HTTPFaultInjection](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPFaultInjection), and it has to be unique <sup>[[source](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#RouteDestination)]</sup>, and unambiguously refer to a service in the service registry <sup>[[source](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Destination)]</sup>, so it cannot be wildcarded (with `*` for example).

Comment: Sorry, did not response in time.  Yes, it answered my question.